# Callkit Call Directory Extension not working with React Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, callkit, call-directory-extension

I want to implement Callkit Call Directory Extension in my React Native App, and created a Bridge too. I've used **objective-c** to handle CallDirectoryHandler. I have built the extension by following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/write-a-native-module-to-detect-caller-id-in-react/write-a-native-module-to-detect-caller-id-in-react-native-b879def0c47c), however, I am still struggling with adding and Identifying numbers. I have tried almost every possible solution, but neither of them worked for me. Below are the codes, I am using:
**CallkitBridge.m**

```
#import "CallkitBridge.h"

#define DATA_KEY @"CALLER_LIST"

#define DATA_GROUP @"group.org.reactn.futurecodes.CallDirectory"

#define EXTENSION_ID @"org.reactn.futurecodes.CallDirectory"

@implementation CallkitBridge

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

-(NSError*) buildErrorFromException: (NSException*) exception withErrorCode: (NSInteger)errorCode {
    NSMutableDictionary* info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [info setValue:exception.name forKey:@"Name"];
    [info setValue:exception.reason forKey:@"Reason"];
    [info setValue:exception.callStackReturnAddresses forKey:@"CallStack"];
    [info setValue:exception.callStackSymbols forKey:@"CallStackSymbols"];
    [info setValue:exception.userInfo forKey:@"UserInfo"];
    
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:EXTENSION_ID code:errorCode userInfo:info];
    return error;
}

- (NSArray*)getCallerList {
    @try {
        NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:DATA_GROUP];
        NSArray* callerList = [userDefaults arrayForKey:DATA_KEY];
        if (callerList) {
            return callerList;
        }

        return [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    @catch(NSException* e) {
        NSLog(@"CallerId: Failed to getCallerList: %@", e.description);
    }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getCallerList: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    @try {
        NSArray* callerList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self getCallerList]];
        resolve(callerList);
    }
    @catch (NSException* e) {
        NSError* error = [self buildErrorFromException:e withErrorCode: 100];
        reject(@"getCallerList", @"Failed to getCallerList bridge:", error);
    }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(setCallerList: (NSArray*) callerList withResolver: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    @try {
      NSLog(@"Caller List -> %@",callerList);
        NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:DATA_GROUP];
        [userDefaults setObject:callerList forKey:DATA_KEY];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
        [CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance reloadExtensionWithIdentifier:EXTENSION_ID completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if(error) {
              NSLog(@"error while reloading");
                reject(@"setCallerList", @"Failed to reload extension", error);
            } else {
              NSLog(@"reloading extension....");
                resolve(@true);
            }
        }];
    }
    @catch (NSException* e) {
        NSError* error = [self buildErrorFromException:e withErrorCode: 100];
        reject(@"setCallerList", @"Failed to set caller list", error);
    }
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getExtensionEnabledStatus: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) {
    // The completionHandler is called twice. This is a workaround
    __block BOOL hasResult = false;
    __block int realResult = 0;
    [CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance getEnabledStatusForExtensionWithIdentifier:EXTENSION_ID completionHandler:^(CXCallDirectoryEnabledStatus enabledStatus, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // TODO: Remove these conditions when you find a way to return the correct result or Apple just fix their bug.
        if (hasResult == false) {
            hasResult = true;
            realResult = (int)enabledStatus;
        }
        if(error) {
            reject(@"getExtensionEnabledStatus", @"Failed to get extension status", error);
        } else {
            resolve([NSNumber numberWithInt:realResult]);
        }
    }];
}

- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport
{
    return @{ @"UNKNOWN": @0,  @"DISABLED": @1, @"ENABLED": @2};
}

@end
```

**CallDirectoryHandler.m**

```
#import "CallDirectoryHandler.h"

#define DATA_KEY @"CALLER_LIST"
#define APP_GROUP @"group.org.reactn.futurecodes.CallDirectory"

@interface Caller : NSObject
@property NSString* name;
@property NSArray<NSNumber*>* numbers;
-(instancetype) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary*) dictionary;
@end

@implementation Caller
-(instancetype) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary*) dictionary {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = dictionary[@"name"];
        self.numbers = dictionary[@"numbers"];
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@interface CallDirectoryHandler () <CXCallDirectoryExtensionContextDelegate>

@end

@implementation CallDirectoryHandler

- (void)beginRequestWithExtensionContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context {
    context.delegate = self;
    if (context.isIncremental) {
        [context removeAllIdentificationEntries];
    }
    NSLog(@"reloaded and adding numbers...");
    [self addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbersToContext:context];
    
    [context completeRequestWithCompletionHandler:nil];
}

- (NSArray*)getCallerList {
    @try {
        NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:APP_GROUP];
        NSArray* callerList = [userDefaults arrayForKey:DATA_KEY];
        if (callerList) {
          NSLog(@"%@",callerList);
            return callerList;
        }
        return [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    @catch(NSException* e) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to get caller list: %@", e.description);
    }
}

- (void)addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbersToContext:(CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)context {
    @try {
        NSArray* callerList = [self getCallerList];
        NSLog(@"Call dir list %@",callerList);
        NSMutableDictionary<NSNumber*, NSString*>* labelsKeyedByPhoneNumber = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSUInteger callersCount = [callerList count];
        if(callersCount > 0) {
            for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < callersCount; i += 1) {
                Caller* caller = [[Caller alloc] initWithDictionary:([callerList objectAtIndex:i])];
                for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < [caller.numbers count]; j++) {
                    NSNumber* number = caller.numbers[j];
                    [labelsKeyedByPhoneNumber setValue:caller.name forKey:number];
                }
            }
        }
        for (NSNumber *phoneNumber in [labelsKeyedByPhoneNumber.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]) {
            NSString *label = labelsKeyedByPhoneNumber[phoneNumber];
            [context addIdentificationEntryWithNextSequentialPhoneNumber:(CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber)[phoneNumber longLongValue] label:label];
        }
    } @catch (NSException* e) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to get caller list: %@", e.description);
    }
    
}

- (void)requestFailedForExtensionContext:(nonnull CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext *)extensionContext withError:(nonnull NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Request failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

@end
```

And this is how I am calling it in my React Native App.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, NativeModules} from 'react-native';

function App() {
  const {CallkitBridge} = NativeModules;
  const callers = [
    {
      name: 'Debt Collector',
      number: '+923100000000',
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const status = await CallkitBridge.getExtensionEnabledStatus();
        if (status === 2) {
          try {
            await CallkitBridge.setCallerList(callers);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('Adding error => ', error);
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Err -> ', error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**P.S:** I have checked the App Group and it is correct, and the +92 is my Country Code i.e. Pakistan, however, I am not seeing the caller ID. I have checked and enable the extension, and I am seeing the Extension Status === 2 which is enabled.
**Please Note:** While I tried every solution, I am unable to debug the Call Directory Extension in XCode. Any help is appreciated, **thanks**.

I tried changing the callers array from name and a array of numbers inside the object, as well as changing a bit the native codes too.
**Expectation:**
I want the Caller ID to be shown, whenever, someone calls me from the number, I provide back from my React Native App.

Comment: "I am unable to debug the Call Directory Extension in Xcode" In Xcode's bar at the top your app will be selected, change it to the extension and then hit run, it'll prompt you to choose an app to run, select your app. When your app calls the extension the extension code will run and you can add debug it just like your app

Comment: User defaults isn't a good choice for doing this, its ok for experimenting with a new numbers, but it your list of numbers grows to hundreds or thousands its not suitable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have now debugged the app, and fixed the issue. Can you please provide me a solution better than User defaults?

Comment: Take into consideration where you're from in the first place and are you going to keep it after it gets added to the extension and how much of it there could be. Also does the data need to accessible to the RN side and the native side? You could store them in a database for example - if the database is located in the group location then it can be accessed by both the app and the extension, or you could just write the data as plain text to a file which again is in the group directory. Which database would depend on your needs and requirements.

Comment: I suggest using a simple shared text file. It can be JSON encoded, or just a CSV.  The phone number is represented as an integer in E.164 format, so the US phone number +1-408-555-1234 would be represented by the integer `14085551234`.  The Australian phone number 02 8424 1244 (which is +61-2-8424-1244) would be the integer `61284241244`.  Your extension must present the phone numbers in increasing order, so sort I suggest you sort your text file before saving it.  Also the extension has a limited memory quota. See https://github.com/paulw11/CallKitTutorial for an example extension in Swift

Comment: My example uses Core Data, but that can run into memory issues if you have a lot of numbers.